# Ordinary and modular representations

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\rho_1,\cdots,\rho_n$ be all the inequivalent complex irreducible matrix representations of $G$.

The representations $\rho_1,\cdots,\rho_n$ of $G$ can be realized over the ring $\mathcal{O}$ of all the algebraic integers.

Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$ and $M\subseteq \mathcal{O}$ be a maximal ideal containing $p$.

Reducing representations $\rho_1,\cdots,\rho_n$ modulo $M$, we get representations $\overline{\rho_1},\cdots,\overline{\rho_n}$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ (namely $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$).

The representations $\overline{\rho_1},\cdots,\overline{\rho_n}$ may not be irreducible.

**Question:** Does the irreducible components (constituents) of $\overline{\rho_1},\cdots,\overline{\rho_n}$ give *all* the irreducible representations of $G$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$?

---

I want to know whether the modualr irreducible representations can be obtained from ordinary representations and decomposition (of course, decomposing a representation may not be easy in general).

This question came because in a book, I saw $2$-modular representations of $A_5$ obtained in this way (See [this link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=cx4PCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=Brauer%20characters%20of%20A5&source=bl&ots=JMPVOsHO6z&sig=Lo_BaftD-lXZFOefPRCkn5sXc5w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC2fLa-vjQAhXJqo8KHVo-C0UQ6AEIWzAJ#v=onepage&q=Brauer%20characters%20of%20A5&f=false))

Comment: I think you need the group to be $p$-solvable to be sure this is the case (in which case I think it follows from the Fong-Schwan theorem).

Comment: But Fong-Schwan theorem concerns lifting every irreducible Brauer character to an irreducible ordinary character, and that theorem may assert that it is possible in p-solvable groups. I am considering "*whether **constituents** of all ordinary irreducible character modulo maximal ideal gives all irreducible Brauer characters*"

Comment: Ahh, good point. I am not sure then.

Comment: The book *Representations of finite groups by Weintraub* obtains irreducible Brauer characters of $A_5$ modulo $2$ from irreducible ordinary characters. I was wondering whether such thing can be done for every group?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The ordinary characters form a basis for the space of class functions on $G$, and hence by restriction span the space of class functions of the $p$-prime part of $G$ which has a basis given by the irreducible Brauer characters.

Maybe more conceptual: Every irreducible modular representation is a quotient of the regular representation, and the regular representation is obviously a reduction mod $p$ of a representation defined in characteristic zero.

Alternatively: You can't always lift a modular representation to characteristic zero, but it turns out you can always lift modular representations that are projective (as $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_pG$ - modules) to characteristic zero.  Every irreducible representation $V$ has a projective cover $P$ (since $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_pG$ is Artinian), so $V$ must occur as a constituent of the reduction mod $p$ of an irreducible factor of the lift of $P$.

Comment: One thing I'd like to add:  It is possible for two non-isomorphic representations over $\mathcal{O}$ to become isomorphic when we tensor with $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.  In particular it is possible for an irreducible representation $\rho$ to have multiple non-isomorphic $\mathcal{O}$-forms which give rise to non-isomorphic reductions modulo $p$.  However it turns out that they will have the same irreducible composition factors (although not necessarily in the same order).